# Elasticsearch - how to search an URL?

Tags: url, search, elasticsearch

I have a problem when I store data like this into Elasticsearch (v 2.3, in AWS):

```
{
  data: {
    url: 'https://www.mydomain.tld',
    someOtherField: 'value',
  }
}
```

index mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "nodes": {
      "properties": {
        "data": {
          "properties": {
            "url": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I didn't find anyway, how can I search queries like:

`http:`, `https:`, `http://`, `https://`, and so on...

**Long story short I need to search URLs, with protocol - an exact partial match.**
Because at least colon is a special mark, searching does not return relevant results, even is field not analysed.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Your mapping is not correct, you're missing a `properties` inside the `data` object. So probably you need to fix this before attempting a query.

Comment: I am sorry, I've extracted this part of mapping from much bigger bunch of JSON and I've forgot it. I have got it `properties` there, and ES returns it to me when I call `GET index/_mapping`. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, just making sure.

Comment: Use ngrams to split the URLs and, at query time, use `terms` filter to make the search.

Comment: Please, can you give me simple example Andrei? How could search terms look like to be working with ngrams and how could be used ngrams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me best worked wildcard like this at this time.
Even if I know it is slow solution, it is the only suitable:

```
{
  query: {
    "wildcard" : { "data.url" : "https://foo*" }
  }
}
```

The prerequisity is to have field not analyzed.